# The service does not run if the app is killed

Tags: android, service, android-studio-3.0, background-service

So I have a service that checks if the Screen is ON or OFF (from [here](http://www.coderzheaven.com/2011/01/18/detect-when-the-android-screen-goes-off-2/)). 
This is the main activity:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        onCreate();
    }
    public void onCreate() {

        IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter(Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_ON);
        filter.addAction(Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_OFF);
        BroadcastReceiver mReceiver = new ScreenReceiver();
        registerReceiver(mReceiver, filter);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        if (ScreenReceiver.screenOff) {

            System.out.println("SCREEN TURNED OFF");
        } else {

            System.out.println("this is when onPause() is called when the screen state has not changed ");

        }
        super.onPause();
    }
    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        // only when screen turns on
        if (!ScreenReceiver.screenOff) {
            System.out.println("SCREEN TURNED ON");
        } else {

            System.out.println(" this is when onResume() is called when the screen state has not changed ");
        }
        super.onResume();
    }
}
```

The Service class:

```
public class UpdateService extends Service {

    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        // register receiver that handles screen on and screen off logic

        IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter(Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_ON);
        filter.addAction(Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_OFF);
        BroadcastReceiver mReceiver = new ScreenReceiver();
        registerReceiver(mReceiver, filter);
    }

    @Override
    public void onStart(Intent intent, int startId) {
        boolean screenOn = intent.getBooleanExtra("screen_state", false);
        if (!screenOn) {
            System.out.println("Screen is off");
        } else {
            System.out.println("Screen is on");
        }
    }

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        return null;
    }
}
```

Receiver:

```
public class ScreenReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    public static boolean screenOff;

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

        System.out.println("onReceive ");
        if (intent.getAction().equals(Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_OFF)) {
            screenOff = true;
            System.out.println("SCREEN TURNED OFF on BroadcastReceiver");
            Log.d("Check", "SCREEN TURNED OFF" );
        } else if (intent.getAction().equals(Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_ON)) {
            screenOff = false;
            System.out.println("SCREEN TURNED ON on BroadcastReceiver");
            Log.d("Check", "SCREEN TURNED ON" );

        }
        Intent i = new Intent(context, UpdateService.class);
        i.putExtra("screen_state", screenOff);
        context.startService(i);
    }
}
```

The above service runs perfectly when the app is sent to the background. But when the app is killed using the task manager, the service does not work anymore. I need the service to work even when the app is killed.

What should I do to enable that? Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason is that your service is running on the same process as the application. If you set `android:process=":yourServiceName"` in the manifest file, your service will start a new process and you can see your service.

Also, do check if your service is actually running using this method

```
private boolean isMyServiceRunning(Class<?> serviceClass) {
    ActivityManager manager = (ActivityManager) getSystemService(Context.ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
    for (ActivityManager.RunningServiceInfo service : manager.getRunningServices(Integer.MAX_VALUE)) {
        if (serviceClass.getName().equals(service.service.getClassName())) {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

To restart the service you can use an AlarmManager inside your onTaskRemoved method of the service.

```
@Override
    public void onTaskRemoved(Intent rootIntent) {

        Intent restartService = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), this.getClass());
        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getService(getApplicationContext(), 1, restartService, PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);
        AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
        alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.ELAPSED_REALTIME, 5000, pendingIntent);


    }
```

Comment: but as aoon as I kill the app, the service is still not running. My device is getting disconnected if I kill the app. How do I test this?

Comment: I have edited my answer. Use the onTaskRemoved method to restart your service when the app is killed.

Comment: the service still gets dead as soon as i remove my app from recents .i.e. when i kill my app

Comment: Can you confirm this by going to developer options -> running services and check if the service exists or not?

Comment: Yes. I attached the link to my full code above. Can you please help me out.

Comment: I checked again. My service is showing in the  developer options -> running services, but the log tags are not printed anymore and the device shows dead.

Answer (score 1):

If they run in the same process, it is obviously that the service is terminated together with your desktop application.

Run your service as a Windows Service / Linux daemon, they have a different lifecycle compared to the processes created by the user. For example, your application will be terminated automatically on logout.

Comment: Any ideas of how I can implement this in the above code?

Comment: What platform are you using? All the imports in your code seem to be gone. My wild guess is that you use Android.

Comment: I am using android studio.

Comment: Then you should label your question as such, and identify people able to help you with Android specific questions.